# If a is true then what will happen to y? does y gets declared?

Tags: c++

in the given code...

```
....  
....  
if(a)  
{  
    int x;  
}  
else  
{  
    int y;  
}  
....
```

if a is true then what will happen to y?
does y gets declared?
will i be able to use x and y after this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is `true`, then `y` never exists -- it only comes into existence after execution enters the block in which it's defined, and if that never happens it never exists at all.

Whichever leg of the `if` statement is executed, the variable(s) defined in that scope are destroyed when execution leaves that scope, so after the end of this code, neither `x` nor `y` exists, so neither can be used at all.